# Register to receive windows messages when an Win32 event is signaled in MFC

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I have a simple MFC dialog app. I would like to do some overlapped I/O. Waiting for the overlapped event handle in a separate thread is a pain. I'm wondering if there is a function call to register a windows message to a waitable handle? Much like how WSAAsyncSelect works, but without the socket and just a generic Win32 waitable handle (event, mutex, pipe, etc).

My environment: Windows XP, Visual Studio 2010

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want to wait for signal instead of infinite "while(flag) Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);"?

Comment: The point of overlapped I/O is to *not* use another thread.   If you use another thread then simply using blocking I/O is much simpler.  Looks like you are not doing it right, impossible to guess why.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm looking for an easy way to do I/O in MFC. I'd rather not deal with threading. WinSock has a really nice way of sending windows messages on socket events. I'm looking for something similar in Win32.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your constraints, I'd use [RegisterWaitForSingleObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to register a callback routine that'll be invoked when the object you waiting on is signaled.

The callback function is simple - it merely needs to ***Post*** a user defined message to the interested window indicating that the event is signaled.

That said, if you're using [ReadFileEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [WriteFileEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or other I/O function that supports a completion callback, you can use that callback to achieve similar functionality.

Comment: RegisterWaitForSingleObject is probably the closest thing in Win32. Thanks Bukes! FYI, ReadFileEx and WriteFileEx require an alterable thread state for completion callbacks. I don't think MFC does that.